# If every partitioning of $X$ has a choice function, is $X$ necessarily well-orderable?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Working over the ZF axioms, it's clear that if $X$ is a well-orderable set, then every partitioning of $X$ has a choice function, by choosing the minimum of each cell.

> **Question.** Does the converse hold?
>
> i.e. If every partitioning of $X$ has a choice function, is $X$ necessarily well-orderable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Suppose that $A$ is a strongly amorphous set. Namely,

1. $A$ is infinite Dedekind-finite set, such that every subset of $A$ is finite or co-finite.
2. Every partition has only finitely many non-singletons.

Now every function with domain $A$ induces a partition and only finitely many fibers have nontrivial choices.

Of course, it is consistent that there are strongly amorphous sets.

Comment: Nice! I wonder if we can get a more natural example, though: is it consistent with ZF that every partition of the reals has a choice function, but the reals aren't well-orderable? (Note that certainly ZF+"Every reals-indexed partition of the reals has a choice function"+"The reals are not well-orderable" **is** consistent, e.g. under $AD_\mathbb{R}$.)

Comment: @Noah: I don't know. I think that Liang Yu and Liuzhen Wu have an idea for a solution, at least that's what Liang left me with a comment on the answer about Borel Hamel bases. But I'm not entirely sure. In any case we don't know if the weaker statement can be consistent "If the reals can be mapped onto $A$, then $A$ can be injectively mapped into the reals".